# slider effects goes missing after 2,3 iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Basically i have made a slider in which a user see the image revoving aroound the three Divs. But the schema for this in code is , i have made 3 sliders which changes their images after a particular time . The only problem in this is i am not able to set the proper timing for iterations. Like i have added the fade in and out effects, but after some time the timing collapse, Could you please tell me the proper way to do it?

This is the sample of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Image</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Rotating Image Slider with jQuery & CSS3" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, rotation, slider, images, slideshow, autoplay, play, pause, css3"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

        <style>
            .quotes{
                display:none;
                float:left;
            }

            .quotes1{
                display:none;
                float:left;
            }

            .quotes2{
                display:none;
                float:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">

            <img src = "images/3.jpg" class="quotes2">
            <img src = "images/1.jpg" class="quotes2">
            <img src = "images/2.jpg" class="quotes2">

        </div>

        <div class="content">

            <img src = "images/2.jpg" class="quotes1">
            <img src = "images/3.jpg" class="quotes1">
            <img src = "images/1.jpg" class="quotes1">

        </div>


        <div class="content">

            <img src = "images/1.jpg" class="quotes">
            <img src = "images/2.jpg" class="quotes">
            <img src = "images/3.jpg" class="quotes">
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



        <script>
//js and 3 functions start here     

        (function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2700)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();

})();


    (function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes1");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2500)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }



    showNextQuote();

})();


(function() {

    var quotes = $(".quotes2");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2200)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }



    showNextQuote();

})();

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so the actuall flow for the slider will be..

 first of all the image A which is on extreme right will fade out and new image will come to its place and A will shift its Position to B, Image B whill fade out and will move to Position c

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kegpzujw/

Comment: I have not added images, please add images as 1.jpg ,2.jpg and 3.jpg . .. it will work. I am not getting how to add images there...

Comment: It is working fine on my machine. If you are facing this shifting effect animation problem , you can do one thing , you can set '.fadeIn(2200)'  constant value in each function so it will fade out all the images at a same time and it will fade in all images at same time , and it will also reflect that A has been shifted to B's position

Comment: actuall flow for the slider will be.. first of all the image A which is on extreme right will fade out and new image will come to its place and A will shift its Position to B, Image B whill fade out and will move to Position c